# Sequence of simple closed geodesics converging to a lamination

Tags: geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-group

This question is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAxWC7g3XC4&list=PLLPxLWYLQlwjrbEtCQRFU30KWkJXudeUk&index=11&t=2781s)
at the time around 44'.

I wonder why would a sequence of simple closed geodesics converging to a set of disjoint curves (lamination). Intuitively, wouldn't a sequence of simple closed geodesics converge to a curve? Is the lamination (to be convergent to) a single curve too?

In the video starting from 44'45, Minsky said we can take a lamination $\lambda$ from a pseudo-Anosov, take one curve and apply the pseudo-Anosov, and we can get a sequence to converge to a lamination. Did he mean the lamination to be convergent to is $\lambda$ itself? If so, how could a curve be a foliation (I think the $\lambda$ from a pseudo-Anosov means it's an associated foliation of the pseudo-Anosov element)? (Don't they have different dimensions?)

I would be very grateful if you could give an easy example to visualize a sequence of curves converging to a lamination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple reason that a sequence of simple closed geodesics $\gamma_i$ might not converge to a single simple closed geodesic: for each $L > 0$, the set of simple closed geodesics of length $\le L$ is a finite, discrete set (in the Hausdorff metric), and therefore $\gamma_i$ converges to another simple closed geodesic $\gamma$ if and only if $\gamma_i=\gamma$ for all sufficiently large $i$.

So if I simply choose the sequence so that $\text{Length}(\gamma_i) \to \infty$ then it does not converge to a single simple closed geodesic.

But on the other hand, fixing a closed hyperbolic surface $S$, the set of closed subsets is compact (in the Hausdorff metric), and so *some* subsequence of $\gamma_i$ must converge to *something*.

Here's an example for you to ponder. Suppose that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are simple closed curves intersecting transversely in a single point. Let $\tau$ be the Dehn twist around $\delta$. Let $\gamma_i$ be the simple closed geodesic that is homotopic to $\tau^i(\gamma)$. Then $\gamma_i$ converges to a lamination with exactly two leaves: one compact leaf, namely $\delta$ itself, and one noncompact leaf that I will denote $\ell$. To describe the appearance of $\ell$, it is a line with two ends, and each end spirals infinitely around and around $\delta$, getting closer and closer to $\delta$.

If you blur your eyes somewhat, it looks like this:

[image]

In this image, $\delta$ is the curve that "goes around the hole", and the original $\gamma$ is a curve that "goes through the hole". As $i$ gets larger and larger, $\tau^i(\gamma)$ starts by following $\gamma$ into the hole, and around the back, and then back to the front on the leftmost contour of the surface, and then spins $i$ times around $\delta$ before closing up.

Comment: Sorry, for $L>0$, what's the $L$?

Comment: Oops, I left out a key phrase. It should make sense now.

Comment: Sorry, for "for each $L > 0$, the set of simple closed geodesics of length $\le L$ is a finite, discrete set (in the Hausdorff metric)," do you require these geodesics to be disjoint? Otherwise, I can't see why they form a discrete set. Also, I wonder why it's a finite set, a bounded discrete set might not be finite in general.

Comment: This is about the space $C(S)$ of closed subsets of $S$, which is a compact metric space with respect to the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). By definition of $C(S)$, the points of $C(S)$ are the closed subsets of $S$. If you did not know, $C(S)$ is the space in which convergence issues of closed geodesics and laminations is set. Since $C(S)$ is a metric space, each finite subset of $C(S)$ has the discrete topology. And the *set* of simple closed geodesics of length $\le L$ is a finite subset of $C(S)$.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain why the set of simple closed geodesics of length $\le L$ is finite? I think it might have infinitely many geodesics of the same length.

Comment: That's a big question in and of itself, quite beyond the scope of this post. It's a fundamental theorem about finite volume hyperbolic manifolds covered in basic textbooks on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, I guess it's finite up to homotopy right? Otherwise, I think we may move a little to generate infinitely many finite-length curves.

Comment: Nope. That's impossible in a hyperbolic manifold. You'll learn that in a basic textbook too.

Comment: Sorry, is the picture you drew $\gamma_1$ instead of the limit? I wonder where the spirals are?

Comment: Also, I think the union of these 2 leaves is connected. Am I right?

Comment: Yes; connected although not of course path connected. Besides that, rather than discuss followup questions in the chat, a much better use of this site is if you write a new question (as long as you can [provide sufficient context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)).